# How defensive should a Bash script be?

Tags: bash

I recently stumbled over a very basic code snippet and began to wonder how defensive a Bash script needs to be.

`[[ -f $file ]] && rm -- "$file" || echo "File does not exist."`

What is the purpose of checking if the file exists when you could also simply pass the file to `rm` and let `rm` do the check itself? If the reason is that you can control what is shown as an error message yourself, why isn't it then necessary to also check if the file is writable in order to delete it? This leads me to believe that if you once start to test for possible conditions before you call a command -- in order to be consistent -- you'd need to check for every eventuality or you'd end up with error messages printed by yourself and those of external commands (`rm`in this case).

Another slightly more complex example I have wondered about would be

`ffmpeg -n -i "./$file" -codec:a flac "./${file%.*}.flac"`

This takes a file and transcodes it with the FLAC codec. Would it be sensible to first check the existence of the input file, whether that file is readable and also whether the location is writable for the output file? (Checking if the output file already exists is already done by providing the option `-n` to `ffmpeg` which means not to overwrite existing files.)

All of these would be checked by `ffmpeg` itself if I wouldn't add these checks.

Comment: You don't need write permission on a file to delete it, you need the write permission on the directory containing it

Comment: How defensive it needs to be is likely to be an opinion question that doesn't have a real answer.  It'll depend on your environment and the cost of a failure.  If it doesn't harm anything if the script fails or does the wrong thing, then it probably doesn't need to be too defensive.  If it could accidentally end up reformating the wrong partition, well, you probably want lots of error checking.

Comment: Controlling the error message is a bug, not a feature.  If this was simply coded as `rm "$file"`, you would probably get an error message (on stderr) that says something useful like: `/path/to/file: permission denied` instead of an incorrect message on stdout.

Comment: @EricRenouf  One of the benefits of not allowing a program to continue execution once an unexpected error occurs is that you protect yourself from consequences you are not expecting (due to incomplete knowledge, the complexity of abnormal cases, etc.).  In my own scripts, I have an error handling approach that provides me with this benefit for very little additional effort (building the thing was not trivial).  I tend to be a bit dogmatic about never defaulting to ignoring failure in scripts because of how simple it has become for me.

Comment: `-f` is not just checking if a name exists, but that it is a *regular file*.  The name given by `$file` could be a directory, fifo, unix socket, or device, in which case the `-f` would fail.  Actually the `echo` message (which should be redirected to stderr) is not totally correct, `-f` failing means that the name is not a regular file, not that it does not exist.

Comment: @Fred sure, I'm not saying there's no reason ever to use error checking, just that "how defensive should it be" is almost certainly an opinion question, not one that is factually decidable in a general case.

Comment: @EricRenouf  I agree.  What I meant is that, as a general rule, people's opinion as to whether something should be done or not is related to how costly/painful it is.  The lack of standard, comprehensive approaches to error handling in shell scripts unfortunately pushes people toward having less robust error handling (compared to a hypothetical situation where better tools were available).

Comment: For the specific case of deleting a file only if it exists, `rm -f -- "$file"` is generally the Right Thing. The snippet is faulty, because `foo && bar || baz` is **not the same as** `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`, even though folks who are sloppy (and accustomed to languages with ternary operators) often treat it as though it were. Thus, the extra error handling in this case is introducing bugs while adding no value.

Comment: ...which is not to say that bash scripts shouldn't be defensively written -- they absolutely should! -- but they should be defensively written **competently**, by someone who actually knows where the pitfalls are (incidentally, the above is [BashPitfalls #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3)).

Answer (score 1):

How defensive your script should be depends on how granular a control you want over execution of your script.

If you are happy with how a command handles failure and the rest of your script can execute without any problem whether it fails or succeeds, you can execute it totally blindly, ignoring its output and return value...

```
command_to_be_ignored >/dev/null 2>&1 ||:
```

Maybe you are satisfied just knowing whether it succeeds or fails?

```
command_to_be_ignored >/dev/null 2>&1 || result=$?
```

If you run a mission-critical script and you want to react to many potential failure modes, then you will need to capture and test the output of the command, or test preconditions and do something different if they are not met.

By the way, checking preconditions to the execution of a command does not make error handling unnecessary, because the command may still fail due to things happening in parallel, or simply you not fully understanding (or being able to test) all potential failure modes.  Checking pre-conditions is used to change what your program does in specific cases, not to avoid handling errors.

To sum it up, it is a matter of engineering : understanding the underlying mechanisms, knowing what you need to do, and making appropriate tradeoffs.